# If frequency decrease and voltage increase

Tags: motor

i wanna ask you if i want to transfer the washing machine which had already worked at 60 Hz and 110 volt to another country has 50 Hz and 220 volt what will been happening to this machine and what the best economic solution to this problem??

Comment: I think the best economic solution would be to sell it on Garage Sale and buy a new machine in the new country.

Comment: The motor will burn up rather quickly if connected to 220 volts. If you buy a transformer to reduce the voltage to about 83% of the voltage marked on the machine, it will not burn up, but it will run at 83% of the original speed and might not wash effectively. The most economic solution is to sell it as mentioned.

Comment: This isn't a "wanna" site.

Comment: As @CharlesCowie states, you would need a transformer to run this machine, however with the currents involved, it will not be cheap, you would be better to sell the old one and buying a new machine. The cost of shipping it will also be significant.

Comment: @CharlesCowie Your Comment should be moved to an answer, as it is the right answer and explains the reasons why

Comment: what Eugene said!

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to discard/sell the machine.

Although it is easy enough to transform one voltage to another, there is no really efficient way to transform frequency. You could theoretically use an AC to AC solid state converter but they're used for industrial applications and are really large and really pricey. If it's an economic solution you're looking for, I'd not recommend that. Machines designed for one frequency are not usually designed to work efficiently at another, and can even cause damage to the machine. So you're better off buying a new one.

Comment: To be fair, the frequency is only of moderate importance.  The motor will rotate a bit slower, which will reduce the efficiency of the machine since it was designed for the kinetic energy transfer at 60hz.  But a simple motor won't be damaged by running it at 50hz.  It would burn up trying to run it at twice the voltage, though.

Comment: Sane advice, but not always the case. The frequency thing is often just a pulley change on the motor. Sometimes the voltage thing is also just a wiring change internal to the appliance, though I somehow doubt it for a residential appliance. If the particular model is also available for purchase in the new country, a retrofit may also be possible.

Comment: You're right. He could just transform the voltage to a lower level. How much will efficiency drop though?

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, your best bet is probably to sell your current machine and buy a new one when you get there.

You can NOT run it directly at 220V. The currents will be twice as much and you will burn out the motor, worse, the wiring may overheat and cause a fire assuming the circuit breaker/fusing doesn't immediately blow.

Further, if it's a modern machine it likely has electronics in it which will be sensitive to over-voltage and will probably fry.

As such, you would need a step-down transformer to run this machine, however with the currents involved, it will not be easy to obtain, or cheap.

The frequency thing is less of an issue assuming there is no real time clock on the machine. It will run mechanically slower as is, which may or may not be an issue, but a pulley change may be all that is required to correct that.

If the particular model of machine is also available for sale in the new country you may be able to have a service guy retro-fit it, but that would also be an expensive undertaking.

You should also consider the cost of shipping. Washing machines are very heavy (there is a large block of concrete in there...) and add a considerable amount to the freight costs.

Comment: (+1) Really the right answer! The shipping cost could be the killer here (maybe more than the step-down transformer) depending on the distance between the two locations. E.g.: sending that bulky and heavy thing from USA to EU would be crazy! It would be interesting to know from where to where the OP would want to ship.

Comment: wondering what the down vote was for.... sigh

Comment: @LorenzoDonati  from  ksa to jordan it's really cheap transmission